# How do I run a python file inside another python file?

Tags: python, operating-system, telegram-bot

I'm working on a mac. I get a Permission denied exception when running code. How do I run one python file inside the main python file?

```
import os
import telebot
from telebot import types
# --------------------------\ project files /-------------------------#
from auth_data import token, txt


bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


# first launch, start of work
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def welcome(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    parse = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Get messages', callback_data='parse')

    markup.add(parse)

    photo = open('menu.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption=txt, reply_markup=markup, parse_mode="HTML")

# menu
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'parse':
            os.system('/Users/valiev/code/python/telegram_bot_parser/parser.py')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: You could `import` it..

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to use a Python executable in your system call.

Answer (score 0):

You are not running the file, but opening it. Try changing

```
os.system('/Users/valiev/code/python/telegram_bot_parser/parser.py')
```

to

```
os.system('python3 /Users/valiev/code/python/telegram_bot_parser/parser.py')
```